# Textarea não redimensiona com o tamanho do valor retornado do server

Tags: html5

Configurei um textarea para redimensionar o tamanho conforme o usuário digita porem quando o valor vem do server o campo fica no tamanho de uma linha apenas. Como resolve isso?

Comment: Poste uma parte do seu código para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Lá aonde está sendo salvo, qual o tamanho máximo do texto?

Comment: $(".textarea-auto").keyup(me.autoResize);


        this.autoResize = function () {
            objTextArea = $(this);
            this.style.cssText = 'height:' + this.scrollHeight + 'px';
        };

Comment: Agora como faço para um campo que sera preenchido por um valor retornado do server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução para quem precisar:

```
    var me = this;

    this.onload = function () {
        me.bind();
    };

    this.bind = function () {
        $(".textarea-auto").keydown(me.autoResize);
        $('load', me.autoResizeLoad);
    };

    this.autoResize = function () {
        objTextArea = $(this);
        this.style.cssText = 'auto';
        this.style.cssText = 'height:' + this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    };

    this.autoResizeLoad = function () {
        var objTextArea = $('.textarea-auto');
        for (var i = 0, inb = objTextArea.length; i < inb; i++) {
                objTextArea[i].style.cssText = 'auto';
                objTextArea[i].style.cssText = 'height:' + objTextArea[i].scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
```